# XAMPP php.ini display error not working

Tags: xampp, php

I want to mute my XAMPP error reporting so I changed `display_error` value from On to Off and then restart the service. But after restarting, I still got the error messages. I have no idea why is it like this.

Comment: What error message are you getting.  Certain kinds of errors (startup errors) could get output regardless of the value of display_errors.

Comment: `Deprecated: Function session_register() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\lang_session.php on line 17` My code is written for lower version of php but it still works. When I refresh the page, the message will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an error from PHP on a script, use

> error_reporting(0);

Edit: Oh. You want to disable it entirely? I wouldn't do it, as you could miss small errors that doesn't cause your page to load.

Comment: I tried that already, but nothing happens. It's fine if the page doesn't load correctly. I just want to mute the message.

Comment: Odd. It works on my file viewer script. Try to check your XAMPP log for any errors.